# Can memcache.cas and memcache.add miss?

Tags: memcached

`memcache.set` can fail if the server load is too high and `memcache.get` can fail if there is no data in the server. These are called `misses`. [Is this terminology confusing because in the `get` scenario, it didn't miss anything, it did everything correctly but there was no data, so the term `miss` is misleading?]

However, would operations like `memcache.cas` and `memcache.add` also have this problem of `misses` and if so how is it defined? I believe they are fundamentally some kind of `set` operation so the `miss` could happen here as well?

I couldn't find an an API documentation that specifies what happens during all scenarios. I am finding that using memcache clients makes it even difficult because each client has its own rules. Currently I am trying to understand at the server level.

Comment: what api you used? i'm using spymemcached, when i get, if the request fail, i got an exception; when the request succeed but get null content, the api get a null value without exception, it seems very clear to me.

Comment: oki. i use python memcached here and its supressing almost everything. atleast thats good to know it is client that is handling it and not server. thanks, I will also try the client you mentioned.